# Print an array in a table using JSTL

Tags: arrays, jsp, jstl

This is an example of an array I have :

```js
String[] dataName = {"Gene Name","Promoter Name","Source","Year","Author"};
String[] proteinList = {"protein01","AOX","Yarrowia","2006","John Doe","protein02","pGAP","Homo sapiens","1997","John Smith"};
```

The actual array can contain up to 30 values.

The display of the data should be in a table like this :

```html
| Gene Name  | Promoter Name  | Source       | Year  | Author    |
| protein01  | AOX            | Yarrowia     | 2006  | John Doe  |
| protein02  | pGAP           | Homo sapiens | 1997  | John Smith|
```

But the result I get is :

```html
| Gene Name  | Promoter Name  | Source       | Year  | Author    |
| protein01  | AOX            | Yarrowia     | 2006  | John Doe  | protein02  | pGAP           | Homo sapiens | 1997  | John Smith|
```

In JSTL, this is how I have written :

```html
<tr>
    <c:forEach items="${dataName}" var="namedata">
    <td class="body" valign="top" align="left"><b><c:out value="${namedata}"/></b></td>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>


<tr>
    <c:forEach items="${proteinList}" var="result">
    <td class="datafield" valign="top"><c:out value="${result}"/></td>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>
```

Is there any ways that I can use loop so that `proteinList[]` will loop to `proteinList[5]` in a new row?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Really, the view should not handle such problems. Create a Protein class, and provide a List<Protein> to the JSP. Using proper objects will make the code clearer and simpler. Storing the attributes of several different objects, as Strings (whereas some should be integers), in a single array, is bad design.

Comment: @JBNizet but the `proteinList[]` array is actually from a query, so I cannot separate the integers from the list.

Comment: Yes, you can. The query should return a List<Protein>. If you need help wit how to return a List<Protein> from a query, then post your code.

Comment: How about using `<c:forEach>` iteration?

Comment: You **will** use c:forEach. But to display a list of proteins using c:forEach, you should first have a list of proteins. Not an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this, insert tr tags when index reaches 5th element:

```
<tr>
    <c:forEach items="${dataName}" var="namedata">
    <td class="body" valign="top" align="left"><b><c:out value="${namedata}"/></b></td>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>

<c:forEach items="${proteinList}" var="result" varStatus="proteinCount">
  <c:if test=((proteinCount.count+1)/5)=0>
    <tr>
  </c:if>
        <td class="datafield" valign="top"><c:out value="${result}"/></td>

  <c:if test=((proteinCount.count+1)/5)=0>
    </tr>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: not exactly working but this give me some idea! thanks a lot!